# What does "uncancellable" mean? / What is a word for "not able to be uncancelled"?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

What does "uncancellable" mean?  Does it mean that something may be uncancelled, or that something may not be cancelled? [Edit:] How would one express each of those ideas?

For bonus points, is there a way to be indicate that something may be not uncancelled?  In-uncancellable?

Comment: See also: *unlockable* :)

Comment: For "*not able to be uncanceled*", how about "*irrevocably canceled*", "*irreversibly canceled*" or "*permanently canceled*"? You could then use "*reversibly canceled*" for "*ununcancelable*".

Comment: @Peter I like those ideas.  I wanted to stick with the canceled theme for the sake of consistency; people might not immediately associate "reinstatable" or something with a "canceled" attribute found elsewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is: it is ambiguous between the two meanings, and one must use context to determine which meaning is intended.  (This is, of course, accepting that *uncancel* is a real word.  I am perfectly willing to say it is; in the past decade or so it has become a very real word in the computing realm.)

This ambiguity is because we have two *un-* prefixes in English.  One attaches to adjectives and means "not" (e.g. *unclear*), and the other attaches to verbs and means the reverse of the action of the verb (e.g. *untie*).  When you have an adjective formed from a verb by a suffix, then it may be impossible to tell how deeply the *un-* prefix is attached; that is:

`un[cancelable]` or `[uncancel]able`

So, if both forms make sense, as they do with *un-cancelable* and *uncancel-able*, then we have ambiguity.

Another good example is *unlockable* ("not able to be locked" or "able to be unlocked").  Yet another one is *untied* ("never been tied at all" or "tied at one time but then untied").

---

Technically speaking, the ad-hoc word for "not able to be uncancelled" (assuming you really want to use one word), would be *ununcancelable*.  For the sake of readability, I would recommend writing it as *un-uncancelable*; that said, the best approach would probably be to use more words :)

Comment: Thanks; that ambiguity is somewhat unfortunate in my situation, but now I know.  The fact that "un-" can be used both ways makes the answer to my second question rather silly.

Comment: PS: Good English for a Russian. ;)

Comment: Excellent answer. I was a bit bothered when I read your comment re "unlockable" against the Q - I really thought I was heading for a logical/lexical minefield. But you've guided me through it safely, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I means that something may not be cancelled - perhaps because there is no mechanism for doing so, or because it is simply not allowed (for example, an order for something to be made).

I don't think there would be a word for "not able to be uncancelled", that's probably too many negatives in a row.

Comment: If this is the case, how would one indicate that something is able to be uncancelled?

Comment: @Josh: using more than one word: "[If no-one else has taken your space] you can reinstate your cancelled appointment", or "You can rejoin the club after cancelling your subscription".

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is ambiguity, though I would read *uncancellable* as being capable of being uncancelled (in the unlikely event of wanting such a phrase) and use *noncancellable* for something which cannot be cancelled (though *irrevocable* is a real word which means much the same thing).

For the bonus *nonuncancellable* for something which is not uncancellable. But it is ugly.